# extending Lua: check number of parameters passed to a function

Tags: c++, c, lua, arguments, argument-passing

I want to create a new Lua function.

I can use function with parameters (I'm following [this link](http://www.dcc.ufrj.br/~fabiom/lua/14Extending.pdf)) in order to read function parameters.

```
static int idiv(lua_State *L) {
  int n1 = lua_tointeger(L, 1); /* first argument */
  int n2 = lua_tointeger(L, 2); /* second argument */
  int q = n1 / n2; int r = n1 % n2;
  lua_pushinteger(L, q); /* first return value */
  lua_pushinteger(L, r); /* second return value */
  return 2; /* return two values */
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to know the number of parameters passed to a function, in order to print a message if user does not call function with two parameters.

I want to execute the function when user writes

```
idiv(3, 4)
```

and print an error when

```
idiv(2)
idiv(3,4,5)
and so on...
```

Comment: The usual practice in Lua is not to complain about extra arguments.

Comment: And what about fewer arguments?

Comment: Fewer arguments is another story. If sensible defaults can be used, then do that. Otherwise, raise an error.

Comment: In fact. I need that user specifies the exact number of arguments that I need. I don't want to use default values because the user should be always aware of what he's using.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`lua_gettop()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_gettop) for determining the number of arguments passed to a C Lua function:

> **`int lua_gettop (lua_State *L);`**
>   Returns the index of the top element in the stack. Because indices start at 1, this result is equal to the number of elements in the stack (and so 0 means an empty stack).

```
static int idiv(lua_State *L) {
  if (lua_gettop(L) != 2) {
    return luaL_error(L, "expecting exactly 2 arguments");
  }
  int n1 = lua_tointeger(L, 1); /* first argument */
  int n2 = lua_tointeger(L, 2); /* second argument */
  int q = n1 / n2; int r = n1 % n2;
  lua_pushinteger(L, q); /* first return value */
  lua_pushinteger(L, r); /* second return value */
  return 2; /* return two values */
}
```